# Flutter Retorfit Variable image type in Multipart while uploading

Tags: flutter, dart, retrofit2, dio

Currently I am using **retrofit.dart** with **Dio** to upload an Image as Multipart file.

```
userImage = File(/*image path*/);
uploadProfileImage(userImage);
```

**Webservice Function**

```
@POST(AppURLs.editProfileImage)
@MultiPart()
Future<NetworkBaseModel<UserResponseModel>> editProfileImageAPI(
    @Part(contentType: 'image/jpeg') File profileImage,
);
```

This works well. However, as you can see in **@Part** annotation, the image type is fixed to **'image/jpeg'**...

What I want is a way to dynamically change this type according to the selected image extension.

Is there a way to do that??